# MapRoute for Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

In ASP.NET MVC we can map URLs to controllers, actions, and parameters. For example, the following MapRoute is the default used in an ASP.NET MVC application.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This means that if we have the url “/value1/value2/value3”, ASP.NET MVC will call the action Value2 of the Value1 controller and the Value3 will be used for the id variable. I want to create something similar with Razor Pages.

My scenario is too complex, so I will try to explain it with a simple example.
For example, I will have a page called "/Pages/Article.cshtml" with the following definition at the top of the page

```
@page "{articlefriendlyname}"
```

This means that I can call the articles page using the following format

```
/Articles/do-something-article
```

In the c# code I will have the following OnGet method:

```
public void OnGet(string articlefriendlyname)
{

}
```

Now I can have the following URLs working on my web application

```
/Article/do-something
/Articles/do-something-else
```

I want these URLs to be called when I have the following URLs:

```
/do-something
/do-something-else
```

This means that I want to define the following URL maps:

```
/{articlefriendlyname}      ==>     /Article/{articlefriendlyname}
```

I could use the root index.cshtml and define the parameters so that I will not have the Articles word in my URL but the root web page will be used for something different so I can not use it for displaying the articles of the website.

I think I can use the approach described in the following article, but I have not succeeded to make it work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/razor-pages-convention-features